# Different results when building with cmd devenv vs. VS2017 IDE

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

When I compile my solution from within the VS2017 IDE, it worked fine.

However, when I run it from a commandline (no matter if from the "normal" commandline or the developer tools' commandline), it fails with the error

```
Inputfile ...\silk_common.lib was created using an older compiler than the other objects. Create old objects and libraries anew.
```

What might be the reason why building from the IDE succeeds while from cmd fails?

Comment: Have you done a Clean?

Comment: Yes, I have done a Clean.

Comment: Can you show your full command lines?